# Chrome apps get grouped in window list

Tags: xfce, chrome, window, panel

I like to have launchers for web applications (spotify web player, google calendar, overleaf etc.). I also like to group multiple open windows of the same application in the window list.

I create desktop launchers for different web apps in chrome via "add to desktop". When I open a web app such as google calendar or overleaf with these launchers, it is grouped with other chrome apps, and the browser window in the window list in my panel.

I use Linux Mint xfce 18.3 and the xfce panel 4.12. Is there any way to make the window list treat chrome apps as separate applications?

I.e., I would like to have the following grouping:

- google chrome browser

  - chrome window 1
  - chrome window 2
- google calendar chrome app
- overleaf chrome app
- ...

Instead I get

- google chrome browser

  - chrome window 1
  - chrome window 2
  - google calendar chrome app
  - overleaf chrome app
- ...

Any suggestions in how to fix that?

Thanks

Note: I edited the question to explain the desired behavior.

EDIT: 2 years later, same problem. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Anybody knows a solution for ubuntu? I'd love to have the feature...

Comment: Actually the new web app manager for linux mint solves most of my issues. You can install it in Mint as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check for options in Panel Preferences. Right click `Panel -> Preferences -> Window Grouping`.

If available, select `Never group windows` option.

[image: Select window list preferences]

[image: Select never group windows]

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. I know this possibility exists but it is not what I want. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thank you for clarifying. Hope you can find an answer. Good luck.